# Modifying of css by document.styleSheets

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-chrome

I try to modify CSS by changing:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fontSize = '1rem';
```

It works perfect at PC, but using mobile browsers (at least chrome & mozilla) triggering of this script makes no effect.

What did I do wrong? If such way of modification of CSS is not globaly supported by some reason, how can I modify CSS different way?

EDIT: I want to change style for of all existing and all future dynamically added objects with exact class. So `el.style.fontSize` is not very good option.

Comment: it is better if you use CSS variables

Comment: According to mdn, [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/styleSheets) is an experimental feature, but is widely compatible. [`CSSStylesheet` Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) may have the answers you need. From that page: "To add or remove items in cssRules, use the `CSSStyleSheet`'s `insertRule()` and `deleteRule()` methods."

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately there's not modifyRule() method :) I'd like to modify existing rule instead of inserting/changing rules/classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying styleSheets directly can be tricky.

I prefer to append a new `style` element to the document and place the modified CSS in there. Since it is the last style element in the document, it will override any earlier CSS rule that has a matching selector.

For example, this will set the font size of the body to 1rem:

```js
let style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = 'body { font-size: 1rem; }';
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Not very elegant, but it seems it's the better stable way to do it as of today. Thanks.

Comment: @YuriyO. It's certainly more elegant than hacking away at an undocumented data structure.

Comment: Haha. I agree :)

Comment: «Since it is the last style element in the document, it will override earlier CSS rules» ...of the same specificity :o)

Comment: @agrm Updated the answer: "it will override any earlier CSS rule that has a matching selector"

Comment: @terrymorse Already implemeted. It works perfect at mobile device. Thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/styleSheets) (about `DocumentOrShadowRoot.styleSheets`):

> This is an experimental technology.
>
> Check the [Browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/styleSheets#Browser_compatibility) carefully before using this in production.
>
> Expect behavior to change in the future.

I would therefore advise against using the method.

I can't, however, explain in any more detail why you're seeing the problem you describe, as most browsers are supposed to support this feature in the linked compatibility table.

---

Now to answer your next question:

> how can I modify CSS different way?

I would always get an element through the DOM first and then apply styles to an element directly. For example:

```js
var myEl = document.getElementById("myId");
```

Then you can do:

```js
myEl.style.fontSize = "1rem";
```

---

If you don't want to target the element by its `id` attribute, you can use several other methods:

1. `getElementsByClassName()` – takes a string value of a class name, eg. `"myClass"`
2. `getElementsByTagName()` – takes a string value of a tag name, eg. `"body"`, `"div"`
3. `querySelector()` – takes a string  value of a CSS selector eg. `"div.myClass p"`

However, these don't return a single element like the `id` selector. For example, to get the first element of a particular class:

```js
var myEl = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0];
```

And the fourth would be:

```js
var myEl = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[3];
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to change style for of all existing and all future dynamically added objects with exact class.

Answer (score 0):

When I last dealt with this manipulating the CSSOM was not supported very well by many browsers (and I think that didn't change yet).

If you want to apply styles to single Element do it on the Element directly.

If you want to generate css rules at runtime you could also consider dropping a style tag into your document:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');

// set style properties
// append the style tag to the head or somewhere in the body

head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Css rules at runtime - it's exactly what I need. Not very elegant solution, but it seems it's the better stable way to do it as of today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have more control using css variables, below you can find a small demo that illustrates my point

```js
let root = document.documentElement;

document
  .querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    let currentVal = Number(getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--defaultFontSize').replace('px', ''));
    root.style.setProperty('--defaultFontSize', `${currentVal + 5}px`);
  });
```

```css
:root {
  --defaultFontSize: 20px;
}

.text {
  font-size: var(--defaultFontSize);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="text">Some text</p>
  
  <button>Increse font size</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have the classname or id of whatever you want to modify , you can use the jquery css() method.

e.g : `$("#whateverID").css('font-size', '1rem');`

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to add a library OP didn't say they were using.

Comment: It's a suggestion of something to use. Does OP need to specify that he's using a certain library or not?

Comment: exactly @SvenWritesCode ..
I used "you can use the jquery css() method"
I didn't oblige him to do so ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to use plain js. Also, as I mentioned above, I want to change style for of all existing and all future dynamically added objects with exact class.